# Check if PHP object can be compared

Tags: php

Some PHP objects such as instances of DateTime can be compared with greater than or less than. Given

```
$time_1 = new DateTime('2016-02-24 15:22:01');
$time_2 = new DateTime('2016-01-30 10:41:29');
```

then the comparison `time_1<time_2` is valid and will evaluate to false.

Comparisons like this can't be done for objects we create from our own classes.

Given an object, is it possible to determine whether it can be compared with the greater than or less than symbols?

Edit:

I'd like some way to test an object is from a class which has overloaded the comparison operators. Eg:

```
class MyClass {}
$obj_1 = new MyClass();
$obj_2 = new DateTime();

has_overloaded( $obj_1 ); //false
has_overloaded( $obj_2 ); //true
```

Comment: please add some more description what you really want to know.

Comment: I suspect that (technically) you can compare any objects with less than / greater than, you just might not get the results you expect.  Please give some more specifics as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can't compare object with `>` or `<`, but you can do it with the properties of that classes. [Doc's Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)

Comment: @FrayneKonok There you go, it even fits nicely in a single line!

Comment: @FrayneKonok I'm not asking 'how' to compare two objects, I'm asking how to find out 'if' an object has an overloaded comparison operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in the PHP documentation. Operator overloading is not possible for any of your own classes in PHP. As mentioned in the article, only some built-in classes support the direct use of operators such as greater than,... As support is only limited to built-in classes, there's no built-in function to check for support. [A feature/change request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9331) has already been created, but support seems to be limited.